# Login customData property using AuthenticationBase

Tags: c#, silverlight, authentication, wcf-ria-services, ria

I'm trying to access the customData property that can be passed to the server via RiaServices.  Similar to: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/0509878c-7315-4f31-84d8-33ee8e9abcf3/additional-login-information Currently we are using the AuthenticationBase provided by System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.ApplicationServices, however it doesn't appear that it will let me hide the existing "Login(...)" method to use my own and gain access to the customData property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code sample from Microsoft demonstrating an implementation of a custom authentication service.  The sample appears to allow you to include the customData in the Login method:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Custom-Authentication-96ca3d20#content

Comment: Thank you for the link I came across it a few minutes ago and it will work, I was just looking to see if there was any way to override the existing AuthenticationBase.  If not, I'll just mark yours as the answer.

Comment: In the discussion on the forum link you referred to, they say that it's not possible to use the default AuthenticationBase.  You have to provide your own implementation for the customData to work.